# Apache Webserver: check if decompression on

Tags: apache, webserver, gzip, compression, deflate

With `SetInputFilter DEFLATE` I can force the apache to decompress incoming messages. Is there a way to ask the webserver whether it supports decompression of incoming request. I would expect a specific HEADER information for that. 
The only HEADER information I know of is: accept-encoding (which is for requests, afaik) and content-encoding (which only tells the client that the response is encoded right?).

Comment: I'd rather ask this on https://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I must admit that the title is a bit misleading. The question is not related to any webserver configuration or anything. I'm writing a proxy as Java application that sends a compressed body to the webserver as long as it supports it, and that's the point: Before I send the compressed data I need to determine whether the webserver can process it.

Comment: It's definitely an httpd/Apache question rather than a programming one, so ServerFault is the way to go